# How to display non-printable Unicode characters in Emacs/AucTeX?

Tags: unicode, emacs, auctex, bidi

I would like to see the non-printable Unicode bidi characters PDF (202C), LRO (202D), RLO (202E) in the emacs editor (but not the pdf output). How can i do this?

EDIT: Here's a minimal working example.

---

```
%% -*- mode: LaTeX; coding: utf-8 -*-
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
    Forward, [202e]drowkcab[202c] and forward again.
\end{document}
```

---

Here [202e] and [202c] stand for the Unicode bidi characters of the corresponding hexadecimal codes, namely RLO (Right-to-Left Override) and PDF (Pop Directional Formatting), respectively. I have entered them using the combinations *C-x 8 **RET** 202e **RET*** and *C-x 8 **RET** 202c **RET***, respectively. The output reads:

> Forward, backward and forward again.

Ideally i would like the characters [202c] and [202e] to show in the emacs editor, but not in the pdf output, as yellow 'C' and 'E', respectively.

Comment: @CharlesStewart Thanks, but from your answer i realize i hadn't posed my question clearly enough. I wish the bidi characters to show on the emacs editor screen, but not in the pdf/dvi output (whether this output is onscreen or printed out).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Emacs and how it displays non-printing chars, not the TeX-specific aspects of using the editor.
